# Does $y = (-1)^x$ where $x∈ℝ$, change exponentially?

Tags: exponential-function, real-numbers

Is $y = (-1)^x$ an exponential curve, or just a sinusoidal one, can it be said to change exponentially as with positive exponents?

---

I'm sure W/A showed this as being sinusoidal with an integer period. But now shows the answer as -1.

From the answers I understand that their is no definitive definition but their is an equivalent with complex numbers, where instead of the real number -1, the equivalent complex number {-1, 0} is used, and that is sinusoidal as described above.

Comment: WHat is your definition of $-1^x$? is it $-(1^x)$, or is it something like $e^{i \pi x}$?

Comment: Negative numbers raised to a power always bothered me, especially when the power is a real number. Best to never use them!

Comment: There is no canonical definition of $(-1)^x$ for $x$ real, except when $x$ is an integer. Which definition do you have in mind?

Comment: I used Wolfram Alpha to view the curve, I do not know these details of they calculated it, it was sinusoidal with an integer period.

Comment: Yes, that is because $(-1)^x = e^{i\pi x} = \sin(\pi x)+ i \cos(\pi x)$. Perhaps you would enjoy a course in complex numbers?

Comment: Sorry, Wolfram Alpha answer now seems to disagree with my earlier request.

Comment: So with real numbers this is sinusoidal, but this is not the definitive answer?

Comment: I really don't understand why this question was downvoted. It's a perfectly valid question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are talking about $-1^x$, then no: $-1^x = -1$.
The expression $(-1)^x$ on the other hand is not defined for most $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

If you mean the complex-valued function $e^{i\pi x}$ by $(-1)^x$, then you get:

$$\Re(e^{i\pi x}) = \cos(\pi x)$$
$$\Im(e^{i\pi x}) = \sin(\pi x)$$

That's probably, what Wolfram Alpha shows you.

Comment: This answer uses notation that is too subtle to be understood. I get you.  But I had to read twice.  And remember rules of operation order (when parentheses usually help).

Comment: The complex version is equivalent to the real version? With -1 the real number being equivalent to {-1, 0} the complex number?

Comment: @alan2here We're defining functions based on different definitions of exponentiation. $x \mapsto (-1)^x: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ has no standard definition since  we don't define the conventional exponentiation that is learned in high school for the negative reals. Complex exponentiation is defined however, so $z \mapsto \exp(i \pi z): \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ is well-defined, and so is the restriction $x \mapsto (-1)^x: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{C}$.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a fun bit of insanity that occurs if we allow formal manipulations of negative numbers raised to a power:

Let $x>0$.  Then $x$ can be approximated by a sequence of rationals $\left\{\frac{2a_n}{2b_n+1}\right\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$, where $a_n$ and $b_n$ are positive integers defined for $n \in \{1, 2, 3\ldots\}$, so that: 
$$ x = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \left[\frac{2a_n}{2b_n+1} \right]\: \: \: \mbox{(Equation 1)} $$
See paragraph at bottom for a formal proof of this.

Now for each $n \in \{1, 2, 3, \ldots\}$ we have:

$$ (-1)^{\frac{2a_n}{2b_n+1}} = ((-1)^{2a_n})^{\frac{1}{2b_n+1}} = (1)^{\frac{1}{2b_n+1}} = 1 $$
where the second equality uses the fact that $(-1)^{even} = 1$, and the last equality uses the fact that any odd root of 1 is 1.  Assuming continuity, we get:
$$ (-1)^x = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} (-1)^{\frac{2a_n}{2b_n+1}} = 1 $$

This holds for all $x>0$, including $x=3$, and so $(-1)^3 = 1$. But of course $(-1)^3=-1$.  So $1=-1$.

---

To understand why (Equation 1) holds, first note that $x$ can be approximated by a sequence of rationals $\{p_n/q_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ such that $p_n$ and $q_n$ are positive numbers for all $n \in \{1, 2, 3, \ldots\}$, and $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} p_n/q_n=x$, so it follows that: 
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{2^np_n}{2^nq_n+1} =\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{p_n}{q_n}=x$$ 
We can simply define $a_n = 2^{n-1}p_n$ and $b_n = 2^{n-1}q_n$, so that (Equation 1) holds.